# Finding a polynomial of degree 3 from a Fourier serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

This is the problem 1.3.8 from Powers' *Boundary Value Problems,* 5th Edition. It says:

> The series
> $$ 
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} \, \sin(nx)
> $$
> converges to a continuous periodic function. On the interval $0 < x < 2\pi$, this function coincides with a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $3$. Find the polynomial.

**This is my attempt so far:**

I started setting the polynomial as
$$p(x)=A+Bx+Cx^2+Dx^3.$$
Since the sum only contains $\sin$ factors, it must be an odd function, so it reduces to
$$p(x)= Bx+Dx^3$$
Then (as the problem suggest) I look for the points where $p(x)=0$, which are $x=0$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{B}{D}}$. Then, evaluating this last point in the series:
$$ 
0 = p\left(\pm\sqrt{-\frac{B}{D}}\right) 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^3} \, \sin\left(n\left(\pm\sqrt{-\frac{B}{D}}\right)\right)
$$
which implies that
$$
\left(\pm\sqrt{-\frac{B}{D}}\right) 
= \pi\Longrightarrow B = -D\pi^2 
$$
so now the function has the form
$$
p(x) = (-D\pi^2)x+Dx^3 
$$
Then, evaluating in the point $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, it turns out that $D=-\frac{1}{12}$, so
$$
p(x) = \left(\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)x 
- \left(\frac{1}{12}\right)x^3 
$$

This is all I've tried, but I'm not sure about the results... am I missing something? Is there anything I'm taking for granted?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be helpful to graph the polynomial versus some partial sums of the Fourier series (although that wouldn't prove you are right)

Comment: Also, you can't go wrong if you just check the Fourier coefficients of your candidate solution, via the integral definition of the coefficients.

Comment: I tried to graph some partial sums of the serie in GeoGebra, but it got stuck and I couldn't verify it... but I'll try to check the coefficients as you told me. Thank you!

Comment: @Maslow It equals $\frac{1}{12}x(\pi - x)(2\pi - x)$ which has zero at $0, \pi, 2\pi$. You can verify it by calculating the Fourier series of this function.

Comment: @Gonçalo No, it doesn't since I didn't consider it when I set the equality...

Comment: @RiverLi I'll go to check it out. Thank you!!

Comment: Let's say the sum converges to g(x). We have p(x) = g(x) for x in (0, 2π). This g(x) is an odd function, but then p(x) and g(x) may not be the same for negative x, so you can't guarantee that p(x) is an odd function. From the result we do see that p(x) is not an odd function.

Comment: @qrsngky Thank you for the observation.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments guys, I think I finally got the solution. Thank you again!!!